# No puedo instalar esta versión de Photoshop

Tags: instalacion

> he tratado instalar el programa de esta manera en más de una ocasión

/ **a tener en cuenta:**

- utilizo ubuntu 20.04
- tengo los programas necesarios para poder instalar este (descargados desde la consola de comandos)
- desargué winetricks desde la aplicación Ubuntu Software

/ **el problema:**

habiendo ejecutado estos comandos desde la consola

```
   git clone https://github.com/Gictorbit/photoshopCClinux
   cd photoshopCClinux
   ./setup.sh
   1 (la opción para proceder con la instalación)
```

y ya finalizada la instalación, se muestra lo siguiente:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/root/.local/share/applications/photoshop.desktop': No such file or directory
error: can't copy desktop entry
```

/

*lo curioso es que, habiendo instalado todos los paquetes que vienen con wine (mono y gecko), se hayan mostrado estas líneas en la consola al iniciar la instalación del programa:*

```
package wine is installed...
package wine64 is installed...
package md5sum is installed...
Warning: package winetricks is not installed.
please make sure it's already installed
would you continue? [N/y] y
```

> y me aseguré de tener winetricks instaladado, pero nada parece funcionar

Comment: No he intentado instalar photoshop en unix, pero tal vez esto te sirva para buscar una alternativa compatible: https://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-photoshop/

Te adelanto que el software GIMP puede servir en general como alternativa, pero si necesitas usar photoshop extensivamente tal vez tener un SO basado en unix no sea lo mejor.

Comment: Como comentario aparte te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y colocarle un titulo que sea una oración con sentido, la frase que pusiste queda en el aire!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.